# Loosing 20 ripples for resetting ledger nano for new seed

Tags: ripple

I setup my ledger nano s properly and transferred my Ripple to ledger nano. Now I want to reset my ledger nano and generate new seed. I have transferred Ripple to some other exchange to reset my ledger but last 20 ripple can't be transferred as it is required for any ripple account. Once I will reset my device, can I use the same ripple wallet so that my 20 ripples won't be lost or I will have to forget these 20 ripples in terms of resetting my ledger nano? Is there any other way to save these 20 ripples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Ledger's Ripple address is tied to the seed, if you reset the device and choose a new seed, you will lose those 20 XRP.

If you reset the device and restore the old seed, you can reuse the address.

There is no way to use a new seed and the old Ripple address on a single ledger.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raghav. I want to change my seed due to security reasons and if I will restore old seed then it won't fulfill my purpose. In that case I will have to lose these 20 ripples. But in future anytime I can reset my ledger with old seed and can access the same old ripple wallet?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can access the old keys at anytime by restoring your previous seed

Comment: I don't know if the ledger supports this (it probably doesn't) but you can change a wallet's key without changing the address. That will let you use a different key/secret but still access the same address and its funds.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You can probably convince the ledger to sign such a transaction, I'm actually exploring that for our exchange at the moment. I'll post an update here if I can get it to work.